# Can I use the 32.768 kHz output from a RTC instead of an external oscillator on a PIC MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, rtc

Using the 28 pin [PIC18(L)F2X/4XK22](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41412F.pdf) and a [DS3231S](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) real time clock. The MCU has input and output pins for an external *secondary* oscillator and the original schematic has no RTC, but an oscillator circuit attached to these pins.

Can I simply use the output from the RTC to feed the input of the MCU or is this an improper way? I will not be programming this setup, I am simply trying to add an RTC to an already crowded board and while *I could* fit it all the 32.768 kHz output from the RTC is temperature compensated and has a much better PPM tolerance.

Comment: Have you considered the effect of running the PIC that slowly? 32 kHz is about 1/500 as fast as the default 16 MHz. Is your software really that undemanding?

Comment: At the moment, the schematic is asking for that oscillator circuit on RC0 and RC1, "secondary oscillator." Not the programmer on this project, only doing the PCB layout and some parts choices. Also, not 100% up-to-date on MCUs, so a data-sheet that long is an undertaking for me to figure out what a programmer would do with an external secondary oscillator.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, but why not use the internal oscillator of the PIC?  There are a few different modes of it, and its accurate enough for most situations.

A couple of things to remember if you use the 32kHz output of the RTC.  Make sure its wired correctly to the PIC clock input.  I believe it gets connected CLKIN, and then CLKOUT gets left floating or needs to be pulled some direction, I don't remember off the top of my head.  The RTC datasheet indicates that the 32kHz is active by default.  If that ever accidentally gets turned off, there goes the whole neighborhood as now the PIC has no clock, and cannot talk to the RTC and turn it back on.

**Addition:** As Nick said, the clock output of the RTC is an open drain.  You will need to add a pull-up resistor to to CLKIN to ensure correct functionality.

Comment: I've asked that question, but had no usable response. It's an NDA project, but I'm getting little in information as to why I'd need an external source. The project went from "use schematic and BOM to create PCB layout" to "redesign most of everything, still looking for someone to program it." The 32Khz output already has a pull-up resistor on my layout, so I think I'm covered there. Will keep scouring datasheets though. Thanks for steering me and answering so far. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's should be possible to clock the PIC by connecting PIC's CLKI to the 32.768kHz output of the DS3231S.  It's an open-drain output, so you will need a pull-up resistor.

Note also that the PIC has an internal RC oscillator with selectable frequency from 16MHz to 31.25kHz.  (Section 2.3 on p.32 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41412F.pdf).)

Comment: Oh, good catch about the OD output.  I didn't notice that while skimming the datasheet.